# RxJava filter 'else'

Tags: android, reactive-programming, rx-android

I want to split my observable like `if/else` statement

Something like:

```
A[] array = new A[10];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = new A(getRandomString(), getRandomInt());
}

Observable.from(array)
    .filter(a -> condition(a))
        .// <--- do stuff  if condition returns true
        .// <- back to parent
    .filter(a -> complexCondition(a)) // filter all elements(!)
        .// <--- do stuff if complex condition returns true
        .// <- back to iterate all elements
```

Is it even possible?

Comment: What's wrong with using an `if` statement in `doOnNext()`, `map`, etc?

Comment: @nhaarman with doOnNext you won't be able to further process the filtered data the RxJava's way.

Answer (score 4):

In Observable does not work in that way, you have to think that the observable is just like a stream, where you can end up with some items, u others.
The most close if/else that you will find in observables will be use GroupsBy.

Here you have some practicle example that I did explaining how works

https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/transforming/ObservableGroupBy.java

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this behaviour is to subscribe to your data twice and filter it differently:

```
Subscription subscriptionA = Observable.from(array)
    .filter(a -> condition(a))
    .subscribe(...) // <-- do stuff for condition A

Subscription subscriptionB = Observable.from(array)
    .filter(a -> complexCondition(a))
    .subscribe(...) // <-- do stuff for condition B
```

Answer (score 2):

To expand on [Ken's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37919672/327648), another option is to "fork" the Observable into the two branches, using the [replay operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/replay.html). This guarantees that the original observable is only called once. This is useful if there's some expensive processing or side effects somewhere in the chain:

```
ConnectableObservable<A> connectable = Observable.fromArray()
    .replay();

connectable
    .filter(a -> condition(a))
    .// <--- do stuff  if condition returns true

connectable.connect(); // do this after the first branch

connectable
    .filter(a -> complexCondition(a)) // filter all elements(!)
    .// <--- do stuff if complex condition returns true

connectable
    .// <- iterate all elements
```

Remember that all branches must handle both the onNext and the onError events.